# Не работает redirect в ajax форме Drupal 7

Tags: ajax, redirect, drupal, webforms, drupal7

Всем привет, у меня следующая проблем:
Есть самописный модуль, который создает многоступенчатую форму на ajax. На последнем шаге, при нажатии на submit, должен происходить редирект на страницу, ссылку на которую генерируется в процессе заполнения формы. Проблема в том, что форма всплывает в colorbox и редирект работает не правильно:
если использовать

```php
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
$form_state['redirect'] = 'some url';
```

перекидывает на страницу вида *sitename.ru/colorbox/my-page?width=800&height=450&maxWidth=1100&maxHeight=680&startStep=1* и выводит на ней json.
Если же просто прописать

```php
drupal_goto('some url');
```

то просто происходит ajax запрос на этот url и все, никакого редиректа. 
Пробовал на submit`е последнего шага убрать ajax, происходит тоже, что и в 1 случае.
При этом на странице формы (не в colorbox) все отрабатывает как надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю что конкретно произошло, но все работает. Если это кому-то поможет, то вот как решилось:
1)У submit последнего шага я убрал ajax обработку
2)Добавил ещё 1 шаг, внутри которого прописал

```php
drupal_goto('Нужный url');
```

3)Profit!